# Video Display in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

Good Day, I am creating an application that will play/display a video, I did have a look at the Kitchen Sink, This is what I have done but it only plays the audio but does not display the video. Code I used:

```
@Override 

 @Override
    protected void postMain(Form f) {

        final MediaPlayer mp = findMPlayer();
        try {
            InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(getClass(), "/Anointed.mp4");
            if (is != null) {
                mp.setDataSource(is, "Anointed/mp4", null);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try mp.setDataSource(is, "video/mp4", null);

Comment: I have tried the code but its still not showing the video but only audio.

Comment: What is the layout of your Form, put the video in a center of a border layout

Comment: I did change the layout of my Form and its now working.

Comment: But when it i rotate the screen, the video doesn't fill the whole screen but just half of the screen. Is there a way maybe i can use to stretch the video to fill the whole screen and be resizable?

Comment: Media has a full screen mode you can activate